# C++ dealing with double inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, serialization

I'm working on data serialization and I have the following problem. I have a class called AttributeContainer which can contain different types of data (point clouds, rgb images, and so on) and I want to serialize it on disk. This class is a std::map where the key is a string and the value is a pointer to a serializable object. So far so good. My problem is caused by the fact that a certain object that I want to serialize does not only inherit from the serializable class and I don't know how to face the situation. This is the code:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, Serializable*> StringSerializablePtrMap;

struct Cloud3D : public Serializable, public std::vector<Point3D> {

. . .

}

class AttributeContainer : public StringSerializablePtrMap{

. . . 

void insertCloud(Cloud3D *c){
     insert(std::pair<string,Serializable*>("cloud",c));
}

. . .

};
```

and the error that I get from the compiler is that, basically, it doesn't know how to convert c to a Serializable object.

Can, please, someone show me how to deal with this issue?

Thanks,

Federico

---

to answer the comments below, this is the compiler output:

```
/home/dede/workspaces/develop/src/srrg_core_map_2/src/srrg_core_map_2/local_map.cpp: In member function ‘void srrg_core_map_2::LocalMap3D::setCloud(srrg_core::Cloud3D*)’:
/home/dede/workspaces/develop/src/srrg_core_map_2/src/srrg_core_map_2/local_map.cpp:76:54: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, srrg_boss::Serializable*>::pair(const char [6], srrg_core::Cloud3D*&)’
     insert (std::pair<string,Serializable*>("cloud",c));
                                                      ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_tree.h:63,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/map:60,
                 from /home/dede/workspaces/develop/src/srrg_core_map_2/src/srrg_core_map_2/local_map.h:3,
                 from /home/dede/workspaces/develop/src/srrg_core_map_2/src/srrg_core_map_2/local_map.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h:206:9: note: candidate: template<class ... _Args1, long unsigned int ..._Indexes1, class ... _Args2, long unsigned int ..._Indexes2> std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::tuple<_Args1 ...>&, std::tuple<_Args2 ...>&, std::_Index_tuple<_Indexes1 ...>, std::_Index_tuple<_Indexes2 ...>)
         pair(tuple<_Args1...>&, tuple<_Args2...>&,
         ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h:206:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/dede/workspaces/develop/src/srrg_core_map_2/src/srrg_core_map_2/local_map.cpp:76:54: note:   mismatched types ‘std::tuple<_Args1 ...>’ and ‘const char [6]’
     insert (std::pair<string,Serializable*>("cloud",c));
                                                      ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_tree.h:63,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/map:60,
                 from /home/dede/workspaces/develop/src/srrg_core_map_2/src/srrg_core_map_2/local_map.h:3,
                 from /home/dede/workspaces/develop/src/srrg_core_map_2/src/srrg_core_map_2/local_map.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h:155:9: note: candidate: template<class ... _Args1, class ... _Args2> std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::piecewise_construct_t, std::tuple<_Args1 ...>, std::tuple<_Args2 ...>)
         pair(piecewise_construct_t, tuple<_Args1...>, tuple<_Args2...>);
         ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h:155:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/dede/workspaces/develop/src/srrg_core_map_2/src/srrg_core_map_2/local_map.cpp:76:54: note:   cannot convert ‘"cloud"’ (type ‘const char [6]’) to type ‘std::piecewise_construct_t’
     insert (std::pair<string,Serializable*>("cloud",c));
                                                      ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_tree.h:63,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/map:60,
                 from /home/dede/workspaces/develop/src/srrg_core_map_2/src/srrg_core_map_2/local_map.h:3,
                 from /home/dede/workspaces/develop/src/srrg_core_map_2/src/srrg_core_map_2/local_map.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h:150:12: note: candidate: template<class _U1, class _U2, class> constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::pair<_U1, _U2>&&)
  constexpr pair(pair<_U1, _U2>&& __p)
            ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h:150:12: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/dede/workspaces/develop/src/srrg_core_map_2/src/srrg_core_map_2/local_map.cpp:76:54: note:   mismatched types ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>’ and ‘const char [6]’
     insert (std::pair<string,Serializable*>("cloud",c));
                                                      ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_tree.h:63,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/map:60,
                 from /home/dede/workspaces/develop/src/srrg_core_map_2/src/srrg_core_map_2/local_map.h:3,
                 from /home/dede/workspaces/develop/src/srrg_core_map_2/src/srrg_core_map_2/local_map.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h:144:12: note: candidate: template<class _U1, class _U2, class> constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(_U1&&, _U2&&)
  constexpr pair(_U1&& __x, _U2&& __y)
            ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h:144:12: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h:141:38: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, void>’
       template<class _U1, class _U2, class = typename
                                      ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h:138:12: note: candidate: template<class _U2, class> constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const _T1&, _U2&&)
  constexpr pair(const _T1& __x, _U2&& __y)
            ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h:138:12: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h:136:27: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, void>’
       template<class _U2, class = typename
                           ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h:133:12: note: candidate: template<class _U1, class> constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(_U1&&, const _T2&)
  constexpr pair(_U1&& __x, const _T2& __y)
            ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h:133:12: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/dede/workspaces/develop/src/srrg_core_map_2/src/srrg_core_map_2/local_map.cpp:76:54: note:   cannot convert ‘c’ (type ‘srrg_core::Cloud3D*’) to type ‘srrg_boss::Serializable* const&’
     insert (std::pair<string,Serializable*>("cloud",c));
                                                      ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_tree.h:63,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/map:60,
                 from /home/dede/workspaces/develop/src/srrg_core_map_2/src/srrg_core_map_2/local_map.h:3,
                 from /home/dede/workspaces/develop/src/srrg_core_map_2/src/srrg_core_map_2/local_map.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h:128:17: note: candidate: constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::pair<_T1, _T2>&&) [with _T1 = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _T2 = srrg_boss::Serializable*]
       constexpr pair(pair&&) = default;
                 ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h:128:17: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h:127:17: note: candidate: constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _T2 = srrg_boss::Serializable*]
       constexpr pair(const pair&) = default;
                 ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h:127:17: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h:124:12: note: candidate: template<class _U1, class _U2, class> constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_U1, _U2>&)
  constexpr pair(const pair<_U1, _U2>& __p)
            ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h:124:12: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/dede/workspaces/develop/src/srrg_core_map_2/src/srrg_core_map_2/local_map.cpp:76:54: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::pair<_T1, _T2>’ and ‘const char [6]’
     insert (std::pair<string,Serializable*>("cloud",c));
                                                      ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_tree.h:63,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/map:60,
                 from /home/dede/workspaces/develop/src/srrg_core_map_2/src/srrg_core_map_2/local_map.h:3,
                 from /home/dede/workspaces/develop/src/srrg_core_map_2/src/srrg_core_map_2/local_map.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h:112:26: note: candidate: constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const _T1&, const _T2&) [with _T1 = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _T2 = srrg_boss::Serializable*]
       _GLIBCXX_CONSTEXPR pair(const _T1& __a, const _T2& __b)
                          ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h:112:26: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘srrg_core::Cloud3D*’ to ‘srrg_boss::Serializable* const&’
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h:108:26: note: candidate: constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair() [with _T1 = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _T2 = srrg_boss::Serializable*]
       _GLIBCXX_CONSTEXPR pair()
                          ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h:108:26: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided
srrg_core_map_2/src/srrg_core_map_2/CMakeFiles/srrg_core_map_2_library.dir/build.make:134: recipe for target 'srrg_core_map_2/src/srrg_core_map_2/CMakeFiles/srrg_core_map_2_library.dir/local_map.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [srrg_core_map_2/src/srrg_core_map_2/CMakeFiles/srrg_core_map_2_library.dir/local_map.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1627: recipe for target 'srrg_core_map_2/src/srrg_core_map_2/CMakeFiles/srrg_core_map_2_library.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [srrg_core_map_2/src/srrg_core_map_2/CMakeFiles/srrg_core_map_2_library.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed
```

Comment: Use dynamic_cast<Serializable*>(c)

Comment: Indeed the compiler is giving no more errors, could you be so gentle to explain me why?

Comment: Could not reproduce your problem, please ensure the code attached is not compiling.

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 I just pasted the relevant portions of code and I changed some class names to make it more readable. I can assure that the code was not compiling.

Comment: This should normally work without a cast, AFAIK. Or at worst static_cast should be enough. Beware that the dynamic cast is very slow (and at the end you might end up adding null pointers to the map, if the object is not really a subclass of Serializable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implicit conversion to the base class should normally work without casting AFAIK, independent of whether or not it is a multiple inheritance (the exception might be if the same class is inherited multiple times through different intermediate base classes).

But what is often the reason for not being able to convert to base class (implicitly) is when the inherited class is **forward-declared** (I myself was burned by that more than once). Make sure that you include the header with the full class declaration before the

```
void insertCloud(Cloud3D *c){
     insert(std::pair<string,Serializable*>("cloud",c));
}
```

Because to know that the `Cloud3D` class is indeed instance of `Serializable`, the complete class declaration must be available. If the class is only forward-declared (`class Cloud3D;`), the compiler doesn't know, that it is in the fact inherited from `Serializable` and does not allow the conversion.

Comment: Yes, it is the case. There's no forward-declaration of the class and I'm including the header with the class definition before calling insertCloud(...)

Comment: Before calling `insertCloud()` is all good, but does not have any effect on this error as described. The Cloud3D header needs to be included before calling `insert(std::pair...)`, i.e. **where the `insertCloud()` is defined** (not only where it is used). Seems to be inline in the class AttributeContainer, so it will need to be included there (in the AttributeContainer header before the class declaration/definition).

Comment: Btw. also make sure that there is not a cyclic dependency between the Cloud3D header and the AttributeContainer header (i.e. that the Cloud3D is not including AttributeContainer header, even indirectly). This could also be the issue, because then the compiler goes to AttributeContainer header when parsing Cloud3D header, without the Cloud3D class being actually defined yet (and even if AttrCont. class includes it again, it is skipped by header guards, otherwise there would be infinite header inclusion loop).